# Which true type editor do you use to create/modify point symbols for GIS?

Tags: cartography, symbology, font

Which true type editor do you use to create/modify point symbols for GIS and what are the advantages and disadvantages of the tool?

I am looking for a true type editor to create/modify custom point symbols used in GIS. Here are some examples of symbols I want to create:

[image]

I am not familiar with the structure of a true type. But I guess that a true type contains many features which are not interesting for GIS (e.g. kerning). So the true type editor should be easy to use by a GIS analyst. I tried to get informations about true type editors by reading some descriptions in WWW (e.g. [FontCreator](http://www.high-logic.com/font-editor/fontcreator.html)). Before I test (or buy) a program I first want to get informations which editor is good for “GIS symbols”.

Both commercial and free solutions are welcome.

Comment: @PolyGeo Thanks for your comment. Reading the [answer of Devdatta Tengshe](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3483/should-shopping-list-questions-be-off-topic-and-closed-on-gis-stack-exchange/3485#3485) I thought my question would be OK. If I ask for “a tool to create these five symbols“ I thought the question would be "too localized".

Comment: I don't think the question needs to be constrained to the five symbols shown as they are just helpful examples showing the level of versatility of the TTF editor required and any TTF editor will be able to create a whole font-set.  What's a more pertinent issue is whether this question is really relevant to a GIS forum, as it is rather tangential being about TTF editors and not really about GIS software use, spatial analysis techniques or cartography (I haven't voted to close the thread though, because making symbols is interesting if not strictly within the remit of this site).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another tutorial on using [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/en/) and [FontForge](http://www.fontforge.org/):

- [Creating icon fonts with vector software (i.e. inkscape) and fontforge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336401/creating-icon-fonts-with-vector-software-i-e-inkscape-and-fontforge)

Comment: +1. Thanks for the approach of creating true type fonts with fontforge based on *svg files (created with inkscape). I like this approach because inkscape is already the standard vector graphic software in our company.

Answer (score 1):

[Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/en/) and [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) are both free and recommended

here is a [tutorial](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aTutorial-cartography_%28basic%29.svg)