# Creating good quality picture marker symbols with ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

I have created a  nice clean symbol in Illustrator. After exporting to .emf format and appending to objects in ArcMap the symbol looks terrible (see Attachment).

Has can I import good vectors into ArcMap?

ArcMap Symbol

[image: Symbol in ArcMAP]

Illustrator Symbol

[image: Symbol Illustdrator]

Comment: I think the "proper" way of doing it is as a font (like .ttf). But I've managed to get bmps to look nice as well, if they are created for (close to) the intended scale.

Comment: Unfortunately, ArcMap **does not use anti-aliasing** of picture marker symbols. (A feature request has been posted at [ArcGIS ideas](http://esri.force.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bvVx)). As a workaround, either use a **png** (or similar bitmap) designed for your scale (losing vector functionality), or **ttf** (losing color information, but antialiasing is supported: [_"text and character marker antialiasing is controlled by the font smoothing settings that are configured in the machine's display settings"_](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00sq0000000w000000)).

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @lavarider (I updated the ArcGIS Idea link):

> Unfortunately, ArcMap **does not use anti-aliasing** of picture marker
>   symbols. (A feature request has been posted at [ArcGIS
>   ideas](https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/5140)). As a
>   workaround, either use a **png** (or similar bitmap) designed for your
>   scale (losing vector functionality), or **ttf** (losing color
>   information, but antialiasing is supported: [*"text and character
>   marker antialiasing is controlled by the font smoothing settings that
>   are configured in the machine's display
>   settings"*](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00sq0000000w000000)).

Comment: ArcPro also handles these symbols way better than ArcMap. I know you wanted this in ArcMap but if you have ArcPro try that as well.